# bsod 1-3times per day, usually within first ~15mins of PC boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, drivers, bsod

I started getting BSOD on my pretty new PC, it is just 1month old bought from electronics store.

I usually get BSOD when PC is just booted, within like first 10-15mins, or when I am afk from PC. It also happened today after ~7hours of use, even when I was not afk. Also like twice, pc just froze without BSOD, and I had to hold computers "turn on" button to force shut down.

Did some research and found those errors in event manager:
[event manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku10T.png)

any idea what should I do to fix it? It is pretty annoying because I work with this PC and to start all job programs over again takes time..

Comment: Take it back to the store. It must still be under warranty. They may replace it or update drivers and assure you it is fixed.

Comment: @John  but I bought it without OS and installed windows 10 myself with kmspico activator, isn't this a software issue? And since I work with this PC I would prefer to fix it myself to avoid losing PC for a day or two

Comment: The Kernel Power error is not usually an operating system issue. Try update ALL drivers including BIOS and see if that helps.

Comment: I would get a boot disk and do some stress testing on it and see if it shows any failures.  I'd give priority to the RAM test.

Comment: Or make a boot USB with another OS (since Windows-to-Go has gone), e.g. Linux, and let that run for a day or two. If that works without failure, then it confirms it's the OS, not hardware, at root cause.